# javascript - pushing arrays in a for loop to an empty global array - fills the global with the last pushed item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a noob to Javascript. I'm having unexpected results saving arrays generated in a for loop to a global array. The global array ends up filled with only the last item saved in the last iteration of the for loop. I've spent a day trying to figure this out and research it but I'm saturated and stumped.

This is a simple abstraction of my problem.

```
var arrays = [];
var array = [];

//I want the 'array' '0' and '2' elements to stay the same
array[0] = "a";   
array[2] = 'b';

for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    //i'd like to change the array[1] element in the loop
    array[1] = i;  

    //and accumulate the changed 'array' from each loop iteration  in 'arrays' 
    arrays.push(array);    
    console.log(array);
}//end for
console.log(arrays);
```

What is outputted is:

```
[a, 0, b]
[a, 1, b]
[a, 2, b]
[[a, 0, b,], [a, 0, b], [a, 0, b]]
```

What I wanted and expected is:

```
[a, 0, b]
[a, 1, b]
[a, 2, b]
[[a, 1, b,], [a, 2, b], [a, 3, b]]
```

I don't understand why 'arrays' is filled with only the last array of the for loop? How can I accumulate the changed 'array' in each iteration of the for loop?

I'm clearly not understanding something basic here but I'm saturated at this point. Thanks for any advice.

Update: Thanks everyone!! - I now understand now that I was pushing a reference to 'array' to 'arrays'. It pushed the same reference each time so all elements of 'arrays' will just be the latest'array'.  I need to push a new array to 'arrays' with .slice(). Also I made an error in my original post which I corrected. array[2]='c' should be array[2]='b'. Thanks

Comment: You are pushing the same array. Object in JS are passed around using their references.

Comment: is your actual output correct? @ibrahimmahrir is correct, but wouldn't it be each one as [a, 2, b]?

Comment: @aw04 It's the famous console log confusion. The first tree lines are logged separately inside the loop. The last line is the log of `arrays` which won't show the value untill you unfold the array.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir right, but shouldn't it be the final value of i, which is 2 not 0?

Comment: @aw04 https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6WTT.jpg! I agree! But not necessarly the true console log result is the one after the unfolding. The one before unfolding is just the value when the log happened (could be OP fault didn't post it right) but console log on object evaluate the value (the real one) on unfolding.

Comment: @Rob: The answers suggesting you slice the array to get a new one are right of course. This is to demonstrate the behavior. Put `array[1] = 'value';` in front of your `console.log`. What happens is: Lets say we have 3 binoculars. Those binoculars are 1 meter from each other. They are set to view "exactly the same place". If you ask someone to go to that place you will see him from all the binoculars. Pushing in the same array is setting the binoculars to display same place. If you push in a different array, it is like rotating the binoculars to view different places.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir oohh that's interesting, i never noticed that tooltip before :)

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Javascript are passed by reference.

You're pushing the same array instance 3 times.

You need to create a new array in each iteration.
In particular, you probably want to copy the existing one:

```
array = array.slice();
```

Answer (score 1):

You were using reference to initial array, and hence all values in final array was getting updated with final value of the initial array. Use Slice() as it creates a shallow copy of the array. Here is the full explanation :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice?v=control

```js
var arrays = [];
var array = [];

//I want the 'array' '0' and '2' elements to stay the same
array[0] = "a";   
array[2] = 'c';

for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    //i'd like to change the array[1] element in the loop
    array[1] = i;  

    //and accumulate the changed 'array' from each loop iteration  in 'arrays'
var temp =array;
    arrays.push(array.slice());    
    console.log(array);
}//end for
console.log(arrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is a problem to reference pointer. Use slice(); Check this code

```js
var arrays = [];
var array = [];

//I want the 'array' '0' and '2' elements to stay the same
array[0] = "a";   
array[2] = 'c';

for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    var newarray  = array.slice();;
     newarray[1] = i;  
    arrays.push( newarray);  
    }
console.log(arrays);
```